decomposition hourly timeseries
I have the following time series data example:
    structure(list(cycle_rounded = structure(c(1604534400, 1604538000, 
1604541600, 1604545200, 1604548800, 1604552400, 1604556000, 1604559600, 
1604563200, 1604566800, 1604570400, 1604574000, 1604577600, 1604581200, 
1604584800, 1604588400, 1604592000, 1604595600, 1604599200, 1604602800, 
1604606400, 1604610000, 1604613600, 1604617200, 1604620800, 1604624400, 
1604628000, 1604631600, 1604635200, 1604638800, 1604642400, 1604646000, 
1604649600, 1604653200, 1604656800, 1604660400, 1604664000, 1604667600, 
1604671200, 1604674800, 1604678400, 1604682000, 1604685600, 1604689200, 
1604692800, 1604696400, 1604700000, 1604703600, 1604707200, 1604710800, 
1604714400, 1604718000, 1604721600, 1604725200, 1604728800, 1604732400, 
1604736000, 1604739600, 1604743200, 1604746800, 1604750400, 1604754000, 
1604757600, 1604761200, 1604764800, 1604768400, 1604772000, 1604775600, 
1604779200, 1604782800, 1604786400, 1604790000, 1604793600, 1604797200, 
1604800800, 1604804400, 1604808000, 1604811600, 1604815200, 1604818800, 
1604822400, 1604826000, 1604829600, 1604833200, 1604836800, 1604840400, 
1604844000, 1604847600, 1604851200, 1604854800, 1604858400, 1604862000, 
1604865600, 1604869200, 1604872800, 1604876400, 1604880000, 1604883600, 
1604887200, 1604890800, 1604894400, 1604898000, 1604901600, 1604905200, 
1604908800, 1604912400, 1604916000, 1604919600, 1604923200, 1604926800, 
1604930400, 1604934000, 1604937600, 1604941200, 1604944800, 1604948400, 
1604952000, 1604955600, 1604959200, 1604962800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), total_fito = c(2884L, 3691L, 3709L, 
2005L, 3437L, 4028L, 3693L, 4811L, 4798L, 4365L, 2258L, 3204L, 
1569L, 5859L, 9864L, 6974L, 4891L, 2812L, 5207L, 4720L, 4567L, 
4928L, 4740L, 2951L, 2449L, 1558L, 5556L, 5068L, 5348L, 6454L, 
6507L, 7755L, 7556L, 6986L, 5649L, 5525L, 4851L, 7967L, 7769L, 
8434L, 8486L, 6490L, 5836L, 4547L, 5794L, 5501L, 5983L, 5430L, 
4633L, 2556L, 5681L, 7791L, 12581L, 8521L, 9137L, 12713L, 9992L, 
9483L, 8455L, 5524L, 4509L, 11443L, 10365L, 10796L, 9621L, 9176L, 
7606L, 7209L, 11328L, 9312L, 9060L, 6303L, 6731L, 8548L, 9363L, 
8651L, 8211L, 16576L, 13381L, 13825L, 12442L, 10464L, 8967L, 
9723L, 7515L, 9832L, 10126L, 14077L, 12292L, 13396L, 11938L, 
11893L, 14420L, 14250L, 12894L, 14489L, 15005L, 14450L, 13027L, 
12085L, 12037L, 12824L, 12087L, 12027L, 12173L, 11920L, 3406L, 
8896L, 6535L, 8835L, 6559L, 9095L, 11347L, 10671L, 8389L, 12459L, 
6292L, 12862L, 9980L, 6321L)), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x59302a8ad540>)

I convert this in a time series object in different ways as following:
library(xts)
df_test <- xts(dados[c(97:216),]$total_fito, order.by = dados[c(97:216),]$cycle_rounded)

or
df_test <- ts(dados[c(97:216),]$total_fito,
              start = c(2020, 11, 05, 00),
              frequency = 24*4) # frequency is N time by N days

But, independently of the way that I use. When I use stl() to decompose my time series:
plot(stl(df_test, s.window = "periodic"))

The following error is returned:
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  erro na avaliação do argumento 'x' na seleção do método para a função 'plot': 'series is not periodic or has less than two periods'

How could I solve this?
Thanks

You need to fix your reprex - dados has 120 observations and you're indexing no. 97 to 216. This results in numerous NA values and therefore these vectors cannot be used as input to xts(). Your issue is not reproducible with the code above.

Are you looking for hourly seasonality like this?
library(tidyverse)

dados <- structure(list(cycle_rounded = structure(c(
  1604534400, 1604538000,
  1604541600, 1604545200, 1604548800, 1604552400, 1604556000, 1604559600,
  1604563200, 1604566800, 1604570400, 1604574000, 1604577600, 1604581200,
  1604584800, 1604588400, 1604592000, 1604595600, 1604599200, 1604602800,
  1604606400, 1604610000, 1604613600, 1604617200, 1604620800, 1604624400,
  1604628000, 1604631600, 1604635200, 1604638800, 1604642400, 1604646000,
  1604649600, 1604653200, 1604656800, 1604660400, 1604664000, 1604667600,
  1604671200, 1604674800, 1604678400, 1604682000, 1604685600, 1604689200,
  1604692800, 1604696400, 1604700000, 1604703600, 1604707200, 1604710800,
  1604714400, 1604718000, 1604721600, 1604725200, 1604728800, 1604732400,
  1604736000, 1604739600, 1604743200, 1604746800, 1604750400, 1604754000,
  1604757600, 1604761200, 1604764800, 1604768400, 1604772000, 1604775600,
  1604779200, 1604782800, 1604786400, 1604790000, 1604793600, 1604797200,
  1604800800, 1604804400, 1604808000, 1604811600, 1604815200, 1604818800,
  1604822400, 1604826000, 1604829600, 1604833200, 1604836800, 1604840400,
  1604844000, 1604847600, 1604851200, 1604854800, 1604858400, 1604862000,
  1604865600, 1604869200, 1604872800, 1604876400, 1604880000, 1604883600,
  1604887200, 1604890800, 1604894400, 1604898000, 1604901600, 1604905200,
  1604908800, 1604912400, 1604916000, 1604919600, 1604923200, 1604926800,
  1604930400, 1604934000, 1604937600, 1604941200, 1604944800, 1604948400,
  1604952000, 1604955600, 1604959200, 1604962800
), class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), total_fito = c(
  2884L, 3691L, 3709L,
  2005L, 3437L, 4028L, 3693L, 4811L, 4798L, 4365L, 2258L, 3204L,
  1569L, 5859L, 9864L, 6974L, 4891L, 2812L, 5207L, 4720L, 4567L,
  4928L, 4740L, 2951L, 2449L, 1558L, 5556L, 5068L, 5348L, 6454L,
  6507L, 7755L, 7556L, 6986L, 5649L, 5525L, 4851L, 7967L, 7769L,
  8434L, 8486L, 6490L, 5836L, 4547L, 5794L, 5501L, 5983L, 5430L,
  4633L, 2556L, 5681L, 7791L, 12581L, 8521L, 9137L, 12713L, 9992L,
  9483L, 8455L, 5524L, 4509L, 11443L, 10365L, 10796L, 9621L, 9176L,
  7606L, 7209L, 11328L, 9312L, 9060L, 6303L, 6731L, 8548L, 9363L,
  8651L, 8211L, 16576L, 13381L, 13825L, 12442L, 10464L, 8967L,
  9723L, 7515L, 9832L, 10126L, 14077L, 12292L, 13396L, 11938L,
  11893L, 14420L, 14250L, 12894L, 14489L, 15005L, 14450L, 13027L,
  12085L, 12037L, 12824L, 12087L, 12027L, 12173L, 11920L, 3406L,
  8896L, 6535L, 8835L, 6559L, 9095L, 11347L, 10671L, 8389L, 12459L,
  6292L, 12862L, 9980L, 6321L
)), row.names = c(NA, -120L), class = c(
  "data.table",
  "data.frame"
))

ts <- ts(dados[, 2], start = 1, frequency = 24)

plot(stl(ts, s.window = "periodic"))


Created on 2024-04-27 with reprex v2.1.0
